# Connection was reset when I try to execute a query in the yii framework

Tags: php, oracle, yii, oracle-call-interface

When I try to connect to my database, everything is ok, but when I try to use the **query()** command to execute a SQL statement I get this error:

> The connection was reset
>
> The connection to the server was reset while the page was

The page doesn't load.

```
$sql = <<<SQL
SELECT
1
FROM
dual
SQL;
$oci=Yii::app()->db;
$command = $oci->createCommand($sql);
$dataReader = $command->query();
```

I'm trying to do this in the index.php page, if I comment the last line, the page load successfully.

I tested the connection with `echo isset(Yii::app()->db);` and I got 1.

I'm using `oci8Pdo.OciDbConnection` class.

EDIT:

print_r($command) result:

```
CDbCommand Object ( [params] => Array ( ) [_connection:private] => OciDbConnection Object 
( [pdoClass] => Oci8PDO [connectionString] => oci:dbname=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=********)(PORT=1521))
(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=********)));
[username] => ***** [password] => ******* [schemaCachingDuration] => 0
[schemaCachingExclude] => Array ( ) [schemaCacheID] => cache
[queryCachingDuration] => 0 [queryCachingDependency] => [queryCachingCount] => 0 
[queryCacheID] => cache [autoConnect] => 1 [charset] => [emulatePrepare] => 
[enableParamLogging] => 1 [enableProfiling] => 1 [tablePrefix] => [initSQLs] => 
[driverMap] => Array ( [cubrid] => CCubridSchema [pgsql] => CPgsqlSchema 
[mysqli] => CMysqlSchema [mysql] => CMysqlSchema [sqlite] => CSqliteSchema 
[sqlite2] => CSqliteSchema [mssql] => CMssqlSchema [dblib] => CMssqlSchema 
[sqlsrv] => CMssqlSchema [oci] => COciSchema ) [_driverName:private] => oci 
[_attributes:private] => Array ( ) [_active:private] => 1 [_pdo:private] => Oci8PDO Object ( [_dbh:protected] => Resource id #51 [_options:protected] => Array ( [3] => 2 ) [_isTransaction:protected] => ) [_transaction:private] => 
[_schema:private] => [behaviors] => Array ( ) [_initialized:private] => 1 
[_e:private] => [_m:private] => ) [_text:private] => SELECT 1 FROM dual 
[_statement:private] => [_paramLog:private] => Array ( ) [_query:private] => 
[_fetchMode:private] => Array ( [0] => 2 ) [_e:private] => [_m:private] => )
```

EDIT2:

```
'db1'=>array(
      'class'=>'ext.oci8Pdo.OciDbConnection',
      'connectionString' => 'oci:dbname=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=**********)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=*******)));',
      'username' => '***',
      'password' => '****',
'emulatePrepare' => true,
      /*
       * enableProfiling and enableParamLogging are working like normal; Default is false.
       */
      'enableProfiling' => true,
      'enableParamLogging' => true,
),
```

Comment: `query()` will give you only the text of your query, you have to use `queryAll()` function

Comment: I used queryAll() too.. same problem...

Comment: you haven't included your database connection config, maybe there's the problem

Comment: `$oci=Yii::app()->db;` is working... I can var_dump it if you want.

Comment: I edited the post with some debug code

Comment: what database are you using?

Comment: @ineersa Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: @FabioCardoso try to change your driver to PDO_ODBC

Comment: @ineersa how can I do that?

Comment: @FabioCardoso by changing connection string if it's installed

Comment: @ineersa I edited the post, are you talking about that connection string?

Comment: @FabioCardoso and 1 more, what system(Windows etc) and server you use (xamp, open server?)

Comment: @ineersa RHEL + apache

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well, apparently the oci8Pdo.OciDbConnection doesn't work in PHP 5.1 so I used CDbConnection with the right charset and it worked well.

Comment: You're using PHP 5.1?!  The last release was 9 years ago and there have been many, many security fixes since then.  Your server must be utterly unsecure.  Please do yourself (as a developer) and the internet (by not running vulnerable out-of-date software) a favour and update to the latest PHP!

Comment: It's an ethernet based app for a company. Update the php to the latest version will cost some hours to modify the atual php app. But I agree with you and I appreciate your concern.

Answer (score 1):

You are using **Yii::app()->db** but your configuration file seems to be using **"db1"**. Can you check it? This problem does not seem to be related to Yii, but simply an inability to connect to the right database system.